# DNS not resolving

Tags: dns, nameservers

Okay, so I am completely stuck on this DNS configuration.  Here's the ingredients:

1. I have the a domain (i.e. "mydomain.com") registered with NameCheap.
2. Within my NameCheap account I have created "glue records" to create my own nameservers, i.e. dns1.mydomain.com and dns2.mydomain.com
3. As per NameCheap's instructions I have changed the nameservers for mydomain.com to dns1.mydomain.com and dns2.mydomain.com
4. In my hosting (OVH) I have created secondary DNS of dns1.mydomain.com and dns2.mydomain.com, specifying OVH nameservers.
5. In my dns settings in OVH for mydomain.com, I have set the nameservers to dns1.mydomain.com and dns2.mydomain.com

Problems.  Can't reach the domain in the browser.  The error I get is that the host won't resolve.  When I try to track the DNS, I am provided with the error, "mydomain.com does not exist in the DNS" and "No IP address or host name with a valid lookup in input."

When I do a Trace DNS Delegation I get the following:

```
Loading root server list (static data):
-> a.root-servers.net (198.41.0.4)
-> b.root-servers.net (192.228.79.201)
-> c.root-servers.net (192.33.4.12)
-> d.root-servers.net (128.8.10.90)
-> e.root-servers.net (192.203.230.10)
-> f.root-servers.net (192.5.5.241)
-> g.root-servers.net (192.112.36.4)
-> h.root-servers.net (128.63.2.53)
-> i.root-servers.net (192.36.148.17)
-> j.root-servers.net (192.58.128.30)
-> k.root-servers.net (193.0.14.129)
-> l.root-servers.net (199.7.83.42)
-> m.root-servers.net (202.12.27.33)
Sending request to "b.root-servers.net" (192.228.79.201)
Received referral response - DNS servers for "com":
-> f.gtld-servers.net (192.35.51.30)
-> i.gtld-servers.net (192.43.172.30)
-> g.gtld-servers.net (192.42.93.30)
-> c.gtld-servers.net (192.26.92.30)
-> b.gtld-servers.net (192.33.14.30)
-> l.gtld-servers.net (192.41.162.30)
-> m.gtld-servers.net (192.55.83.30)
-> k.gtld-servers.net (192.52.178.30)
-> a.gtld-servers.net (192.5.6.30)
-> e.gtld-servers.net (192.12.94.30)
-> d.gtld-servers.net (192.31.80.30)
-> j.gtld-servers.net (192.48.79.30)
-> h.gtld-servers.net (192.54.112.30)
Sending request to "a.gtld-servers.net" (192.5.6.30)
Received authoritative (AA) response:
-> Header: Non-Existent Domain
```

Here are my DNS records in OVH settings:

```
111.2.333.444 / 24  PTR mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.   NS  dns1.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.   NS  dns2.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.   A   111.2.333.444
mydomain.com.   MX (10) mail.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.   TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all
ftp.mydomain.com.   CNAME   mydomain.com.
imap.mydomain.com.  A   111.2.333.444
mail.mydomain.com.  A   111.2.333.444
ns.mydomain.com.    A   111.2.333.444
pop.mydomain.com.   A   111.2.333.444
pop3.mydomain.com.  A   111.2.333.444
smtp.mydomain.com.  A   111.2.333.444
webmail.mydomain.com.   A   111.2.333.444
www.mydomain.com.   CNAME   mydomain.com.
```

I've obviously misconfigured this.  Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually have your own name servers servicing your domain (which I doubt) you need to set the name servers for your domain to the actual servers providing DNS. You also need to set up your host A records on those name servers.

It looks like you need to be using OVH name server addresses as name server records for your domain, and on the OVH name servers you set your A records for your host.

Comment: Mike, yeah, that's what the points #2 and #3 allow me to do within namecheap.  When I whois my domain, it shows the nameservers as I have set them.  However, somewhere along the line in OVH, I've done something wrong.  I'll definitely go in and look at the A records now, thanks.

Comment: I updated my question and added the current DNS settings from OVH host.

Answer (score 0):

Ping the 2 original OVH nameservers and write down the IP of both.
I assume you already know these IPs as these are the same as the one in your GLUE

Then add this to your existing zonefile:

```
dns1.mydomain.com.  A   1.1.1.1 (where 1.1.1.1 is the IP of the 1st nameserver)
dns2.mydomain.com.  A   2.2.2.2 (where 2.2.2.2 is the IP of the 2nd nameserver)
```